# .NET External Communication

Tags: c#, wcf, communication, tcp, p2p

I used the term "External Communication" simply because I do not mind which method I need to use to be able to send a simple message like "hey, how's it going?" to another person on a different computer who's also running my application.

I've tried literally hundreds of samples, edited them, corrected various errors, came up with some of my own stuff, and nothing ever works.

I can send and receive messages to myself on the same computer but I can never be able to get a friend to connect to my server program. Using port 80, or 8080, or 1009 but i've also tried many other numbers too lol - no luck! I've read documentation many times, and several articles from all over the web and also used those examples, still no luck.

Does anybody have any idea on how i can send and receieve simple messages between computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a classic case for a WCF app with peer-to-peer binding.

Check out some of those links for articles and blog post that show you have to do it:

- [Peer-to-peer programming with WCF in .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297274.aspx)
- [Building a REALLY simple WCF P2P application](http://team.interknowlogy.com/blogs/paulrohde/archive/2009/08/05/building-a-really-simple-wcf-p2p-application.aspx)
- [Chosing the right WCF binding](http://weblogs.asp.net/spano/archive/2007/10/02/choosing-the-right-wcf-binding.aspx)
- [A simple peer to peer chat application using WCF netPeerTcpBinding](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/Chat_application_using_WC.aspx?msg=3159939)

Marc

Comment: Thanks for that :) Does that mean that I have to re-create my whole program over again in WCF? I'm using WinForms

Comment: No - WCF is the communications layer that handles sending back and forth the messages. It work well with Winforms, WPF, web - any app you might dream up! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Is this on a Lan or over the public internet?  I ask as firewall rules may be different in either case.

Use a packet sniffer like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see what packets are travelling on the source and destination ports on both PCs.

Comment: this is over the internet, thanks for the link i'm checking it out now :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a firewall installed on your computer? Rembeber that newer versions of Windows come with a firewall installed and working.

In case you haven't seen it: [Peer-to-Peer Programming with WCF and .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297274.aspx)